# Spring cloud stream kafka committing event on error

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

In my `spring cloud stream` application when having a kafka consumer, I don't want it to commit the event in case of error from an unhandled exception
There is not acknowledgement happening for events throwing exception from my side.

But the current behavior is that it retries the fixed number of time and commits the event. I have tried all possible config but could not find a solution.

But at the same time if I don't acknowledge an event which does not throw an exception that behave normally by not committing it.

My config :

```
spring:
cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        topicConsumer-in-0:
          destination: broker-record.v2
          group: group.v2-local
          consumer:
              multiplex: true
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9093
          configuration:
              max.poll.interval.ms: 1080000
        bindings:
          topic-in-0:
            consumer:
              auto-commit-offset: false
              auto-commit-on-error: false
              ack-mode: MANUAL


spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        topic-in-0:
          content-type: application/json
          consumer:
              max-attempts: 5
              back-off-initial-interval: 10000 #10sec
              back-off-max-interval: 900000 #15min
              back-off-multiplier: 1.5
      function:
        definition: myConsumer
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

Sample consumer code:

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StockEventConsumer implements Consumer<Message<StoreStockMovementEvent>> {

    @Override
    @CircuitBreaker(name="stockEventCircuitBreaker", fallbackMethod = "onCircuitBreakerOpen")
    public void accept(Message<StoreStockMovementEvent> storeStockMovementEventMessage) {
        Acknowledgment acknowledgment = storeStockMovementEventMessage.getHeaders()
            .get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, Acknowledgment.class);
        StoreStockMovementEvent payload = storeStockMovementEventMessage.getPayload();

        try {
            //processing code
        } catch(HandledException ex) {
            //handled exception
        }
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    }

    public void onCircuitBreakerOpen(Message<StoreStockMovementEvent> storeStockMovementEventMessage, CallNotPermittedException exception) {
        log.error("Circuit breaker is open. Message will not be acknowledged to allow retry {} ", storeStockMovementEventMessage.getPayload().eventHeader().id());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide it as a small sample application where we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @sobychacko I added the sample consumer code

Comment: Are you throwing an exception without acknowledging the message? Since you don't have DLQ enabled, the max-attempts settings won't work, and the binder will fall back to the container retry defaults (10 times) and then commit. If I understand it correctly, that is what you are observing. If the code reaches your `acknowledge()` call, then the framework will commit that message.

Comment: We added a note in this ref docs section recently related to this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/4.1-SNAPSHOT/kafka/kafka-binder/dlq.html#_enabling_dlq

Comment: If you still have issues after reviewing my last comments, please provide a formal (minimal) sample application on GH with enough details to reproduce, and we will look into it further.